# iPod volume control problems

Tags: ipod-touch

I recently purchased an apple iPod touch 4th gen but the volume control has been stuck at the max and will start going up or down at any random time The up button doesn't work and the down volume will turn it down but it will go right back up. I've tried turning it on and off but to no avail.

How can I get my volume control back?

Comment: Have you tried a hard reset yet?

Comment: It looks like a hardware problem, I'd suggest that you contact your reseller or Apple.

Answer (score 1):

If your volume control adjusts itself after you restore the device to factory settings, it's likely a hardware error in a button or the headphone jack.

Therefore the steps to fix this are:

1. Back up your device
2. Restore the device
3. Take it in for service (assuming the issue doesn't resolve itself)